# Kendo PIVOT GRID doesn't work with multiples filters

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, pivot

i just started to use Pivot Grids and i think that they have a lot of problems!! But more specifically look this [dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/uFEze/3) that doesnt work!!

If you change this

`filter: {
    "logic": "or",
    "filters": [
         { "field": "[Geography].[City]", "operator": "eq", "value": "Auburn" },
         { "field": "[Geography].[City]", "operator": "eq", "value": "Abingdon" }
     ]
}`

to this

`filter: {
    "logic": "or",
    "filters": [
         { "field": "[Geography].[City]", "operator": "eq", "value": "Auburn" },
     ]
}`

works!! So seems KENDO PIVOT GRID CANNOT SUPPORT MULTIPLE FILTERS.